# Using Javascript to embed Calendly in a survey

Tags: javascript, redcap, calendly

I'm using REDCap 13.9.3.

I'm trying to embed Calendly in a survey so participants can schedule their own appts and for some reason, I can't make the Javascript Injector work. Sorry about the basic question, but where am I supposed to put the src code? It can't be placed on the field itself since redcap fields can't accept  tags, and it doesn't work if I put it as a snippet in the Javascript injector itself. I know I have the right settings because I tried it with an online tester and my calendar shows up:

[image: calendly testing on https://jsfiddle.net]
[image: Calendly on RedCap problem]

Edit: the snippet works fine and for some reason Calendly wasn’t loading at that point. It works fine if you inject the Javascript code in a snippet and create a div with that id in the REDCap field.

Answer (score 0):

First, I note that you have also asked this in the REDCap Community and I can see you're getting good help there. But for others who may come across this, I think injecting JavaScript might be overthinking this.

Did you know that you can use the video embed function in a descriptive text field to embed any webpage in a REDCap form/survey?

If your Calendly booking system has a single URL (which I guess is the `"url"` attribute in your `Calendly.initInlineWidget` options object), then first try putting that in the Video URL field in a descriptive text field. Both inline and popup options should work for you.

Here's an example I knocked up with a Google Appointment Booking form. Same thing really. It just loads the URL in an iFrame.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks but the problem is that I need to embed several videos or other functions in one field. Finally the JavaScript injector worked really well. For some reason calendly was offline or something so I thought it wasn’t working. But it was!

Comment: Why do they need to be in a single field? You can have as many descriptive text fields as you want, and each can embed a single video or URL.

Comment: I need to be able to define a CSS and scripts on a div with a specific ID to use javascript. Is not as simple as copy paste a URL. I finally made it work using more complex javascript using the Shazam module.